# Pull data from array in mongodb, if data is more then 10 minutes older and temporary is true

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is my data

```
"data": {
        "_id": "5d7d265fe4157f1710679848",
        "firstName": "camperf44",
        "lastName": "camperl2",
        "balance": 300,
        "maximumUsable": "100",
        "transactions": [
            {
                "_id": "5d7d265fe4157f171067984a",
                "date": "1970-01-01T00:00:11.545Z",
                "description": "this transection for camp only",
                "amount": 200
            },
            {
                "_id": "5d7d265fe4157f1710679849",
                "date": "1970-01-01T00:01:28.787Z",
                "description": "this transection for camp only",
                "amount": 300
            },
            {
                "_id": "5d7d269fe4157f171067984b",
                "amount": -100,
                "description": "Order",
                "date": "2019-09-14T17:42:55.335Z",
                "temporary": false
            },
            {
                "_id": "5d7ddc22e4c84a10a4bfe504",
                "amount": -100,
                "description": "Order",
                "date": "2019-09-15T06:37:22.732Z",
                "temporary": true
            }
        ]
    }
```

Now from here I need to pull out the data which is having temporary = true and date is 10 minutes older from current time.
I tried by below but it is not working

```
CamperModal.update(
    {},
    {
      $pull: {
        walletTransections: {
          temporary: true,
          date: {$gt: new Date(Date.now() + 10 * 1000)}
        }
      }
    },
    {multi: true}
  )
```

Please find me solution.

Comment: Note that adding `10 * 1000` you are adding 10 seconds, if you want to add 10 minutes that should be `1000 * 60 * 10`

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer actually I was doing little wrong but yes finally I done this by following way

```
CamperModal.update(
    {},
    {
      $pull: {
        walletTransections: {
          temporary: true,
          date: {$lt: new Date(Date.now() - 10 * 60 * 1000)}
        }
      }
    },
    {multi: true}
  )
```